# Java support for PMML

Tags: java, pmml

I am new in PMML, [Predictive Model Markup Language](http://www.dmg.org) and I was wondering if there is some kind of Java support (Open Source / professional) for creating/parsing PMML files.

Initially I only have in mind the possibility of creating/parsing PMML files programatically from Java environments.

I have been "googling" and I have found several possibilities:

- Open source `jpmml` from PMML 3.2.
- JDM's `javax.datamining`, however it seems dead... Does someone have more info?
- Professional library [Zementis](http://www.zementis.com/pmml_tools.htm).
- Use an XML Java library and build DIY parser/writer of PMML files.

I appreciate all your opinions.

Thanks in advance

Oscar

Comment: maybe related: [examples-of-wrapping-open-source-machine-learning-software-in-pmml](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/14072/examples-of-wrapping-open-source-machine-learning-software-in-pmml)

Comment: Thanks mbq, you are right it is quite related. Weka is a nice one, but its license is not compatible in my environment. In the case of Rattle, it is just a front end of r, and I was looking for something like a Java API. T

Comment: Please, don't [cross-post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7280845/java-support-for-pmml).